BlocProvider stackoverflow in flutter app
Im working with a large team developing flutter app.
The architecure used for the app is GoRouter with BLoC.
Since using the mentioned structure every page is directly created from main app in widget tree.
And since the creation every BLoC needed was provided in main app.
Now the provided BLoC's are too many and it causes stackoverflow.
The particular way is to provide each BLoC where it's needed(which I'm planning to do in future).
But for now I need to solve this issue and most of the BLoC's are used globally in the app so the provide statement should persist in main.
Any work around to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.
Ps: It took me long time to understand the overflow was because of too many blocproviders used in widget tree.
Landing widget is somewhat like below:
    void main() async {
      HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
        storageDirectory: kIsWeb
            ? HydratedStorage.webStorageDirectory
            : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(),
      );
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => BlocA()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => BlocB()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => BlocC()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => BlocD()),
. 
.
.
.
// about one hundered Blocs
]
)
child: MaterialApp.router(....)
}


Could you provide some snippets to understand what you mean by "every page is directly created from main app in widget tree "and "since the creation every BLoC needed was provided in main app"

@pcba-dev I added the code snippet as you asked and will provide work around I found at the time please do recommend better solutions . Thank you.

Could you answer the questions from my previous comment. It is still unclear what is your project structure

@pcba-dev well the whole structure can be described as: we use GoRouter for navigation which makes each screen independent and we use bloc for state management which are provided in main app

A solution that came up by one of my coworkers was using get_it which was already implemented.
I registered each Bloc in locator and provided them using locator too!
registeration:
void main() async {
      GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;
      locator.registerLazySingleton<BlocA>(() => BlocA());
      HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
        storageDirectory: kIsWeb
            ? HydratedStorage.webStorageDirectory
            : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(),
      );
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }

different usages:
instead of:
context.read<ChequeServiceBloc>().add(ChequeServiceGetUserDetailsEvent());

I used:
locator<ChequeServiceBloc>().add(ChequeServiceGetUserDetailsEvent());

for BlocBuilder, BlocConsumer and BlocListener I had to provide bloc as example below:
BlocConsumer<BlocA, BlocAState>(
      bloc: locator<BlocA>(),

but the remaining issue is:

what are the consequences?
how to use context.watch, context.read and context.select?
do I have any mistakes in the usage of the bloc?

And I should mention this is a great way to use Bloc without the need of BuildContext.
